# Extjs - check if fields are not the same

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form in ExtJS, with 2 dropdown boxes with a list of languages. They both have the same values, that are loaded from a database table via a JSON datastore.

Its a "From" language and a "To" language.

Now what i want to do is to filter out the language from "From" dropdown in the "To" dropdown, to be sure that same language is not chosen in both dropdowns.

Hope this makes sense :)

/Sune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use the filterBy function instead, and define your own function that will return true for every record besides that specific one:

```
onBlur: function(){
    ds_language_to.filterBy(function(record) {
        if (record.get('language') != fromCombo.getValue())
            return true;
    });
}
```

Substitute the appropriate code to get the value selected in the from combo.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need two separate stores with identical content for this one. When a value is chosen from combobox A (the "From"  combobox), filter that value out from the other comboboxes (the "To" combobox) store. And vice versa. The combobox should reflect the changes almost immediately if configured correctly.

Example quoted from [ExtJS API docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/) to display how to filter contents of a store:

```
store.filter([
{
property     : 'name',
value        : 'Ed',
anyMatch     : true, //optional, defaults to true
caseSensitive: true  //optional, defaults to true
},
//filter functions can also be passed
{
fn   : function(record) {
return record.get('age') == 24
},
scope: this
}
]);
```

You probably need to use a function for the filter since you want to filter out the value that is *not* equal to something.

Comment: Not sure exactly how i should implement this. I have 2 seperate datastores now. What im looking for is to filter the second the dropdown is clicked. I have tried:

     onSelect: function(){
       ds_language_to.filter([
        {
        property     : 'id',
        value        : '12',
        anyMatch     : true, //optional, defaults to true
        caseSensitive: true  //optional, defaults to true
        }]);     
     }

Comment: Filter like that would only leave the item with id 12 in the store, which was probably not what you wanted. As I said, (and as Keylan also explained) you need to use a function for the filter.